# Using session variable in the Model or the other way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to select from the database table the image where username = session[:username]

```
Cover.where(username: session[:username]).select("image").last
```

But I can't use session in the Model. So, what is the other way to show the result of my statement in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, just make method in model and pass username as argument and call it in controller:

`app/models/my_model.rb`

```
# some code here

def self.my_method(username)
  Cover.where(username: username).select("image").last
end

# some code here
```

`app/controllers/my_controlller.rb`

```
# some code here

def my_action
  @record = MyModel.my_method(session[:username])
  # some logic here
end

# some code here
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But when I wrote <%= image_tag("http://example.az:3000/uploads/covers/#{@path}") %> it writes "No route matches [GET] "/uploads/covers"". How can I fix it?

Comment: where is come from variable `@path` ?

Comment: On the example.az/ index view page I wrote <%= image_tag("example.az:3000/uploads/covers/#{@path}") %>. Just in reload the page the url prints like: src="http://bookworm.az:3000/uploads/covers/#<Cover:0x007f9eb0c76b08>" and in logs writes no route matches

Comment: looks like `@path` variable `nil`. Try debug what inside `@path` variable.

Comment: No, it's not nil. Because in logs writes << SELECT  "covers"."image" FROM "covers"  WHERE "covers"."username" = 'my_username'  ORDER BY "covers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1 >> And the result is not null, too

Comment: it is just `sql` query log it not mean that something have in `@path`, add `puts @path.class` and look in log, if see `nil` what's mean `@path` equal `nil`

Comment: NilClass

=> nil

So, how can I repair it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67984/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-).